# Uncaught TypeError: this.props.comments.map is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

I have just started coding in React,I try to code a commentbox ...However, I am getting TypeError: this.props.comments.map is not a function and Uncaught TypeError: comments.concat is not a function...I am kind of lost and am wondering where I am wrong. Can someone please guide me and tell me where I am going wrong?

and this is my react code

```
class Comment extends React.Component{
    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                <div className="comment-author">
                    -{this.props.author}
                </div>
                <div className="comment-body">
                    {this.props.children}
                </div>
            </div>


        );
    }
}

class CommentList extends React.Component{
    render(){
        var commentsNode=this.props.comments.map(function(comment,index){
            return <Comment
                key = {'comment-' + index}
                author={comment.author}>{comment.body}</Comment>
        });
        return(
            <div className="comment-list">
                {commentsNode}
            </div>
        );
    }
}
class CommentForm extends React.Component{
    handleSubmit(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log(this,e);
        const author = this.refs.author.getDOMNode().value.trim();
        const body = this.refs.body.getDOMNode().value.trim();
        const form = this.refs.form.getDOMNode();
        this.props.onSubmit({author:author,body:body});
        console.log(author,body);
        form.reset();
    }
    render(){
        return(
            <form className="comment-form" ref="form" onSubmit={(e)=>{this.handleSubmit(e)}}>
                <input type="text" placeholder="your name" ref="author"/>
                <input type="text" placeholder="your comments" ref="body"/>
                <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
            </form>
        )
    }
}

class CommentBox extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super();
        this.state= {
            comments: props.comments||[]
        };
    }
    loadDataFromServer(){
        $.ajax({
            url:this.props.url,
            dataType:"json",
            success:(comments)=>{
                console.log(comments);
                console.log(this);
                this.setState({comments: comments});
            },
            error:(xhr,status,errInfo)=>{
                console.log(errInfo.toString);
            }
        })

    }
    componentDidMount(){
        console.log('into DOM')
        this.loadDataFromServer();
    }
    handleNewComment(comment){
        const comments = this.state.comments;
        const newComments = comments.concat([comment]);
        const strComment = JSON.stringify(comment);
        this.setState({comments:newComments});
        console.log(comment);
        $.ajax({
            url:this.props.url,
            dataType:"json",
            type:"POST",
            data:strComment,
            success:(comments)=>{
                this.setState({comments:comments});
            },
            error:(xhr,status,err)=>{
                console.log(err.toString());
                this.setState({comments:comments});
            }
        });


    }
    render(){
        return(

            <div className="comment-box">
                <h1>Comments</h1>
                <CommentList comments={this.state.comments}/>
                <CommentForm onSubmit={(comment)=>this.handleNewComment(comment)}/>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
box = React.render(
  <CommentBox url="http://localhost:8080/react-test/json"/>,
    document.getElementById('content')
);
```

Comment: Did you verify the ajax call in CommentBox component is returning data correctly? The comments are set as null probably somewhere, use console.log statements to track down the source of error.

Answer (score 0):

This is mainly because you are tying to iterate an array but what you have received from the ajax call is not an array. Check whether you are receiving an array for `comments` in the ajax call.

Answer (score 0):

As others have stated, this means that `this.props.comments` isn't an array. Maybe it's an object or some other data type. React proptypes can help you catch, debug and fix issues like this. When you run the app and you're passing in a prop which data type doesn't match what you've said it should be in the proptypes it will print a warning in the console.

Just after your `CommentList` and before your `CommentForm`, add this:

```
CommentList.propTypes = {
  comments: React.PropTypes.array.isRequired
  // only add the '.isRequired' if the prop actually is required
};
```